# Mysql: How to get value through many conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the following data:

```
product_id  | product_attribute_id | value
    1       |         1            | red
    1       |         2            | XL
    1       |         3            | 300g
    2       |         1            | black
    2       |         2            | XXL
    2       |         3            | 400g
```

If I want to get the products have value: red, xl, 300g, what should I do?

Please everyone give me advice!

Comment: This smells like a homework question.  What you should do is to show some effort and then ask here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Learn Mysql? product_id keys should be UNIQUE...

Comment: @ChristianBonato This looks like an Entity-Attribute-Value table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model - so `product_id` should not be a unique primary key in this table because it's actually a foreign-key.

Comment: What do the values all have in common? Select it thru that condition.

Comment: Thanks Dai. Learned something today. Pretty hard for a full stack dev to follow up. I work with in-house MySQL databases, and made an habit of creating primary keys in all my tables by default since 2001 has an habit. What would be the use case? EDIT — Never mind, I Wiki'ed. Thx again.

Comment: Is there a foreign table? Like 'attributes'? It would be greatly simplify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is an self-`INNER JOIN` for each attribute, but this does not lend itself well to parameterization, as you'll have to use Dynamic SQL if you have a varying number of parameters.

You haven't said what the table name is, so I assume it's `eav`.

```
SELECT
    a.product_id
FROM
    eav AS a
    INNER JOIN eav AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id AND b.value = 'red'
    INNER JOIN eav AS c ON a.product_id = c.product_id AND c.value = 'xl'
    INNER JOIN eav AS d ON a.product_id = d.product_id AND d.value = '300g'
```

Another approach is to get all rows where the values are in the desired set, then `GROUP BY product_id` and compare the `COUNT` of unique `product_id` values (from each matched `value`) with the expected number (in this case, 3):

```
SELECT
    product_id
FROM
    eav
WHERE
    value IN ( 'red', 'xl', '300g' )
GROUP BY
    product_id
HAVING
    COUNT( product_id ) = 3
```

If this were Microsoft SQL Server, you can convert `IN ( ... )` to an `INNER JOIN` on a table-valued parameter so you don't need to use Dynamic SQL - however I don't know what the MySQL equivalent is:

```
DECLARE @values TABLE ( value )
INSERT INTO @values ( value ) VALUES
( 'red' ), ( 'xl' ), ( '300g' ); -- this is an example, in reality this would be generated by your application/client code

SELECT
    product_id
FROM
    eav
    INNER JOIN @values AS v ON eav.value = v.value
GROUP BY
    product_id
HAVING
    COUNT( product_id ) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @values )
```

Comment: Um. I feel like this is over complicating it. I think he's just looking for a SELECT and WHERE

Comment: @bmarkham It's not possible to query the database as the OP describes it with a single first-order query without any kind of `JOIN` or correlated-subquery (which will always be inferior to a `JOIN`). Entity-Attribute-Value tables are difficult to work with and this demonstrates why.

Comment: i agree with bmarkham, since the op question is not too clear :v

Comment: @Dai OP described a table with values in it. All he said was "I have this table. How do I get these values".